# Is it possible to recover a deleted APFS volume?

Tags: macos, partition, apfs, disk-volume

Nothing’s been changed or formatted. The “container” is not mounted and the volume I accidentally deleted still shows up in the Boot menu at startup.

How would I go about recovering this APFS volume?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Comment: If the drive is and data is NOT mission critical try using disk warrior. At the very least it will be able to mount the old partition so you can rsync data off it.

Comment: @user136952 - DiskWarrior unfortunately can't yet handle APFS.

Comment: DiskWarrior 5.2 actually does support APFS.

Answer (score 1):

Most commercial file recovery utilities for the Mac also will perform recovery of deleted partitions. Disk Drill Pro, EaseUS, Stellar Data Recovery Pro, etc.

Primary concern is avoiding writing anything to the drive with the deleted partition. Don't run any disk repair/maintenance utilities or attempt to re-create the partition. Avoid using the affected drive (and if it's the boot drive of the Mac, then the Mac itself) at all if possible. My suggestion would be either:

- boot the Mac into Target Disk Mode and run recovery software from a different Thunderbolt-connected Mac
- (if your recovery software offers this option) create a bootable recovery USB drive on a different Mac and boot the affected Mac from it